# How do you pass an expression built from functions and variables defined elsewhere to exec() or eval()?

Tags: python, scope, exec, eval, global

I have a project that requires deployment in several locations. The code is required to be the same at each location with customization defined in a config file. Most of the config file will be dictionaries of integers but in some cases expressions will be include functions defined in the code. I am using `eval()` to interpret the text containing these expressions but I'm running into problems related to scope. My first attempt included the following lines of code

```
temp_text="np.round(get_last_3_values_avg(data,'Qty',sku),decimals=0)"
new_val=eval(temp_text,globals())
```

where `get_last_3_values_avg` and variables are defined elsewhere.
This code produces an error saying that the variables are undefined. I've also tried

```
ex_st='def tempfun():\n\treturn '+temp_text
exec(ex_st)
a =tempfun
```

but this produces the same error. I've also tried defining a variable rather than a function in the text string but got the same results:

```
ex_st='var='+temp_text
exec(ex_st)
a =var
```

Another attempt was to try to retrieve the function in the locals dictionary:

```
ex_st='def tempfun():\n\treturn '+temp_text
loca={}
exec(ex_st,globals(),loca)
a = loca['tempfun']
```

but I get the function rather than a value returned by the function. I've also tried passing the variables to the function. To deal with this I tried a lambda function:

```
def outer(data,sku):
    return lambda q: loca['tempfun'](data,sku)
temp=outer(data,sku)
```

where `tempfun` is modified to take variables but I get the same problem. Is there a way to read a line of code as a string with exec or eval with the text in that string referring to variables and functions defined elsewhere? I should also mention the code will be run locally at a computer only qualified engineers will have access to so the security concerns regarding `eval()` are minimal. Thanks

Comment: You can pass the local and global namespace to `eval`. But note, you should really reconsider this design, it's unwieldy. If you are already writing python expressions, why not simply use a module of functions?

Comment: Note, of *course* `exec` returns the function, not the result of calling the function, because your expression simply *defines a function*. So `a = locat['tempfun']; a()` will actually *call the function*

Comment: What exactly means "defined elsewhere"? In same module or other module you imported?

Comment: I agree with @juanpa.arrivillaga, I would address the design issue before anything else.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. The functions defined elsewhere are custom functions imported from a module.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the allowing code in a config file is awkward and should be changed but I wanted to state the solution to the question was achieved in case someone else has the same question. The solution was to embed the code into a function as stated in the question:

```
ex_st='def tempfun():\n\treturn '+temp_text
loca={}
exec(ex_st,globals(),loca)
a = loca['tempfun']
```

and then as explained by juanpa.arrivilla:

```
desired_value=a()
```

if tempfun() needs to access any variables, they might need to be added as arguments input to the function. I had to add all possible variables to the function and let it use whichever were called in temp_text. This is very awkward. The solution I used instead is to allow the value in the config file to be a dictionary that specifies the location of the data and also a string value determining how the data should be processed (keyword read by a function) as the key with all the processing of the data in a module rather than in the config. Thanks for the help!